# How do I set an ETag on Azure CDN Content when it is pulled from a blob?

Tags: azure, blob, cdn, etag

I have linked my Azure CDN to the storage directly so that the cdn pull content directly from the blob. Google is not happy that there is no ETag and I am unable to find how to set this on blob content. Content pulled from my Web Api App was easy to configure. I am assuming others need this functionality and it is hidden in Microsoft docs somewhere I cannot find.

Answer (score -1):

> The cache validator can be a Last Modified timestamp set by calling SetLastModified, or an etag value set by calling SetETag.

You can call either `Response.Cache.SetETag` or `Response.Cache.SetLastModified` to set ETag. Check details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-manage-expiration-of-cloud-service-content#setting-cache-control-headers-in-code)